# Undefined symbol - Symbol lookup error

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, sfml

I am trying to compile the SFML 2.0 tutorial with Eclipse. The program compiles fine, but when I run it I get the following error:

> /home/eXistys/workspace/SFML/Debug/SFML: symbol lookup error: /home/eXistys/workspace/SFML/Debug/SFML: undefined symbol: _ZN2sf12RenderStates7DefaultE

Under *GCC C++ Compiler > Includes*, I have:

- `/home/eXistys/SFML/include`

and under GCC C++ Linker I have:

- `sfml-graphics
- `sfml-window
- `sfml-system

What could this be? Google gives no results, SFML forums gives nothing useful and I can't find anything truly related on stackoverflow.

Here's the code I compiled successfully (the source code of [this tutorial](http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/start-linux.php)):

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(300, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::Text text("Hello SFML");

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(text);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I downloaded the latest snapshot of SFML 2.0 from here: https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML

Kind regards,

Comment: Have you added the SFML libraries to the project options in eclipse?

Comment: Yes, I have. Under GCC C++ Compiler > Includes, I have /home/eXistys/SFML/include and under GCC C++ Linker I have /home/eXistys/SFML/sfml2-build/lib and sfml-graphics, sfml-window, sfml-system in that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is `sf::RenderStates::Default`. It is declared in RenderStates.cpp, which should be part of sfml-graphics. Are you sure, that sfml-graphics is linking with your program? Is rpath set correctly? I assume that you are building program executable and not a shared library, right? Have you tried to do `LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/sfml-graphics/lib.so /path/to/program`

Comment: If I follow your last step, I get the following: eXistys@linux-djdf:~> LD_PRELOAD=/home/eXistys/SFML/sfml2-build/lib/libsfml-graphics.so /home/eXistys/workspace/SFML/Debug/SFML
/home/eXistys/workspace/SFML/Debug/SFML: symbol lookup error: /home/eXistys/SFML/sfml2-build/lib/libsfml-graphics.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2sf6Window6createENS_9VideoModeERKSsjRKNS_15ContextSettingsE

Comment: Also, I'm sure I linked sfml-graphics correctly. I do not know what you mean with rpath, though.

Comment: Apparently you haven't likned sfml libraries correctly. Now you are missing sfml-window. Please post result of `ldd /path/to/program` and linking command from Eclipse (if available).

Comment: You have linked to SFML library located in /usr/lib64/, while you would rather have one from /home/eXistys/SFML/. Does the version matches between these two?

Comment: There should be C-Build view in eclipse with raw compiler output, could you post the content?

Comment: It might be a Console tab (Window | Show view | Console).

Comment: **** Build of configuration Debug for project SFML ****

make all 
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

**** Build Finished ****

Comment: As you could see, only path /home/eXistys/SFML/sfml2-build/lib is passed to library search path to linker command, while you should have something like

    `g++ -L/home/eXistys/SFML/sfml2-build/lib -L/home/eXistys/SFML/sfml-graphics/lib -L/home/eXistys/SFML/sfml2-system/lib -L/home/eXistys/SFML/sfml-window/lib -o "SFML"  ./main.o   -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system`

Comment: sfml2-build is my folder that contains /lib/. sfml2-build is the result of me compiling SFML with cmake.

Comment: Are all libraries in sfml2-build/lib? You have mentioned multiple directories in linker list.

Comment: It seems, that at least on my system /usr/lib instead of the one given in -L option. You could fool your running environment with `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/eXistys/SFML/sfml2-build/lib /home/eXistys/workspace/SFML/Debug/SFML`

Comment: Oh and somebody edited my question and screwed it up. With the different paths. I'll try that LIBRARY_PATH now.

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH, not just LIBRARY_PATH.

Comment: Weird,   bash: home/eXistys/workspace/SFML/Debug/SFML: No such file or directory
   I've triple checked. It's all written well and the file is there.

Comment: Haven't you missed slash in front of home?

Comment: Oh something went wrong with me typing it, but it works now! The program started succesfully. However, would that require me to do the LD_LIBRARY_PATH every time? is that practical? I'd like to just be able to run it from Eclipse.

Comment: You could either move your SFML to /usr/lib64 or set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to make Eclipse put it in environment for you.

Comment: After removing the SFML lib files in /usr/lib64 and copying the contents of /lib/ to /usr/lib64 it works perfectly! I use Opensuse 12.1 64 bit with GNOME3, for people who might've found this problem through google/stackoverflow :)